# How can I view the content of images when accessed via "Delete Clip Data" in Ditto?

Tags: windows, clipboard, ditto

I saw some large image in my clipboard history managed by the Ditto program, when clicking on `Delete Clip Data`:

[image]

How can I view the content of these images?

Answer (score 1):

- Select an image into the Clipboard buffer.
- Paste the image into a viewer, such as MS *Paint* or *IrfanView*.

Comment: Thanks, "Select an image into the Clipboard buffer": how do I find that image amongst the many other clipboard items in the Clipboard buffer?

Comment: The same way you select any other item from the **Ditto** application into the **Clipboard** buffer.